# Является ли "впрочем" в данном случае вводным словом?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

### "Впрочем(?) всё, что я буду творить".

– Здравствуй, Петя, ты будешь публиковать в журнале только свои рассказы?

— Да. Впрочем(?) всё, что буду творить.

Comment: Запятая после "впрочем" ставится.

Ответ Пети не очень понятен. Или он собирается писать еще и стихи, и романы, и все это публиковать?

Публиковать где, а не куда. Публиковать в журнале.

Comment: Первая фраза неоднозначна, поэтому я и запутался. 1. Собирается ли Петя публиковать только свои рассказы или и чужие тоже? 2. Собирается ли Петя публиковать свои только рассказы или стихи тоже?

Comment: Петя будет пробовать себя в других жанрах, так скажем.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы оформила этот диалог таким образом:
— Здравствуй, Петя. Ты будешь публиковать в журнале только свои рассказы?
— Да. Впрочем, всё, что буду творить.

Считаю, что *впрочем* в данном контексте — вводное слово, требующее обособления (собеседник переходит к другой мысли или, высказывая свою мысль, испытывает нерешительность, сомнение).

1. [впрочем](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC&all=x)
   I. союз (присоединяет предложение или его часть, ограничивающие и уточняющие смысл предшествующего). Однако; тем не менее; всё же. Я знаю его тайну, впрочем не я один. Пособие значительное, впрочем и его не хватает.
   **II. вводн. сл.** Выражает нерешительность, колебание, сомнение.
   — Будешь пить чай?
   — Нет, впрочем, налей!
2. В первой реплике я бы разделила слова говорящего на два предложения:
   сначала "мы здороваемся" — точка;
   потом "мы спрашиваем" — вопросительный знак.

Answer (score 1):

Слово ***впрочем*** выражает сомнение, колебание. Оно может быть вводным словом, в также союзом, если соединяет предложения или части предложения. Однако в обоих случаях оно **обособляется**.

Подробности в справочнике Трудные случаи русской пунктуации (2012) http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_107

Предложенный диалог выглядит **некорректно по смыслу.** Вариант правки (Петя хотел сначала публиковать только рассказы, но потом решил, что будет публиковать всё):

— Здравствуй, Петя, ты будешь публиковать в журнале **только  рассказы?**

— Да. **Впрочем,** **пожалуй**, всё, что буду писать.